# Need to generate new pattern in SQL

Tags: sql

I am having a table with two row as (Pointer, Number), set of number e.g.(11111111,23456789,12345678).

I need to update Number field in table with a new pattern as per my pointer.
I want somthing like:

if my pointer is 1, i need 11111111,23456789,12345678,

if 2 i need 23456789,12345678,11111111..

Comment: Can you give a clearer example of what you have now, and what your desired results are. Consider using http://sqlfiddle.com to construct a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a table like this?

```
create table PointerNumber (
    Pointer int,
    Number1 int,
    Number2 int,
    Number3 int,
    Number4 int
)
```

Do you have data like this?

```
insert into PointerNumber (Pointer, Number1, Number2, Number3, Number4) 
  values (1, 11111111, 23456789, 12345678, 44444444)
```

Now depending on your Pointer column, you want to update the Number to a new pattern? What would be the logic exactly?

The update might look like this perhaps:

```
update PointerNumber set
  Number1 = Number2,
  Number2 = Number3,
  Number3 = Number4,
  Number4 = Number1
where Pointer = 1
```

Verify:

```
select * from PointerNumber
```

Let us know

Comment: Thank you all for your response. Actually i have table:
insert into Pointernumber(pointer,number) values (1, 11111111,22222222,33333333,44444444)

now what i want is can i rotate the numbers in update command keeping my pointer constant

Comment: @sudhakumari, [1st normal form](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/sql-criteria-for-normal-forms.html) would help a lot I think. Is there a valid reason why you keep multiple values in one column? It is possible to play with strings in SQL but it's definitely not advisable. Would you rather improve your design or still try to figure out how to mix up that string of numbers?

Comment: well i'll still try to mix up string of numbers. I have done this via python, but still wants to find a way to get this done in sql. Thanks.